# Monaco editor - Programmatic folding

Tags: monaco-editor

Anybody else find Monaco difficult?

I have the API docs open in several tabs and am crawling all over it trying to glean actual information on *how things work*.

But the docs are *extremely* blank. Just no actual contextual information. They're like adding a comment to the line `i++;` as `// Add one to i`

I have the editor... "functioning". I'm resorting to stepping through the code in `editor.main.js` trying to see how it works!

I'd like to **add** a folding rule. Not **replace** the existing one(s).

`monaco.languages.registerFoldingRangeProvider('javascript...`

I added a folding rule which makes a single block of "import" statements a foldable block. Great. Super!

But that kills all other folding. The term "register" usually implies adding. Not replacing.

Do they actually not want people to use this? Because the API docs, while *technically* correct are hostile. I checked monaco questions here on StackOverflow and 90% of them have *zero* answers. Why do they not document it properly?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the way to do this is create `Selection`s

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/docs.html#classes/Selection.html#constructor

So use the `findNextMatch` method:

https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/docs.html#interfaces/editor.ITextModel.html#findNextMatch

... No, in fact you have to wrap that in a method of your own because that *always* wraps back round, and you need to have a failed find of the next block so you can keep finding the blocks you want until you can't find any more.

So find the start of a block you want to fold, and then find the end, and push a Selection onto an array (as long as the end isn't inside on of the selections you already created - you need to keep searching while that condition is true).

```
selections.push(new monaco.Selection(hideStart.range.startLineNumber, 1, hideEnd.range.endLineNumber + 1, 1));
```

Where `hideStart` and `hideEnd` are the https://microsoft.github.io/monaco-editor/docs.html#classes/editor.FindMatch.html results from finding the blocks.

When you have all the selections, you must then

```
    // Add and collapse each range separately, otherwise only the outermost ranges will be collapsed
    // Must use for loop because forEach doesn't await
    for (let i = 0, { length } = selections; i < length; i++) {
        myMonacoEditor.setSelections([...codeEditor.getSelections(), selections[i]]);
        await myMonacoEditor.getAction('editor.createFoldingRangeFromSelection').run();
    }
```

When creating selections, the innermost ones must be created and pushed onto that array first, so if for example you have

```
    tasks : [
        { id : 1, startDate : '2023-05-15', duration : 5, name : 'Welding 1', eventColor : 'red' },
        { id : 2, duration : 10, name : 'Welding 2', eventColor : 'pink', percentDone : 60 },
        { id : 3, duration : 0, name : 'Welding 3', eventColor : 'purple' },
        {
            id         : 4,
            name       : 'Floor',
            eventColor : 'violet',
            expanded   : true,
            children   : [
                { id : 5, duration : 5, name : 'Foundation', eventColor : 'indigo' },
                { id : 6, duration : 15, name : 'Paint', eventColor : 'blue', percentDone : 25 },
                { id : 7, duration : 2.5, name : 'Drying', eventColor : 'cyan' }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

You have to find that `children` array first, and create that range first before you find the `tasks` one so that the loop above will *add* and collapse each selection one by one so you end up with clean looking code on load of the editor.

That has had to be all gleaned from hacking and googling and guessing and trying crap in the debugger.

`'editor.createFoldingRangeFromSelection'`??? Who'd a thunk it? I can't even remember where I found that incantation.

Hope this helps people because those "docs".... I mean... in my book that's not documentation.